# Extrair dados de um array em javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array, e em seus índices tem um valor serializado. Gostaria de separar esses valores e colocar cada valor em um outro array (com índices devidamente separados). Segue meu código:

```
data = ["["RibS7K/JS+ZTYtjDxqh5hg==","lO/CWn5lb3eqCkDhm9PpwA=="]", "["teste a","teste b"]", "[24351,24352]", "["png","png"]", "["teste a","teste b"]", "[7,6]", "[107.0,99.0]"]

newObject.idCrip = data[0];
```

Quando vou colocar em `newObject.idCrip` recebe `data[0]`, ele fica com `["RibS7K/JS+ZTYtjDxqh5hg==","lO/CWn5lb3eqCkDhm9PpwA=="]` e não com dois valores separados e isto está me atrapalhando. Alguma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não posso afirmar com certeza porque o código que você postou é inválido (falta escapar várias aspas), mas imagino que você esteja atrás disto aqui:

```
newObject.idCrip = JSON.parse(data[0]);
```

Isso funciona se você tem aquela primeira array como string dentro da array de fora. Faltou converter para objeto.

[Demonstração](http://jsfiddle.net/d7khR/)

Comment: gostaria apenas de retirar os valores de `["RibS7K/JS+ZTYtjDxqh5hg==","lO/CWn5lb3eqCkDhm9PpwA=="]` para ficarem `RibS7K/JS+ZTYtjDxqh5hg==` e `lO/CWn5lb3eqCkDhm9PpwA==`

Comment: Você tentou o que eu sugeri? Funcionou? Aquilo retorna um array, com o primeiro valor na posição zero e o outro na um.

Comment: Funcionou @bfavaretto! Valeu mesmo!